# GPS coordinates (Latitude and longitude) are not displaying in my textview

Tags: android, gps, location, fusedlocationproviderapi, wearables

I've been following 2 tutorials and neither ones have worked, I made sure I had the permission and dependencies added.

This is my code:

```
      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_location);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        gps_loc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
        gps_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gps_btn);
        next_act = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_activity);

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        gps_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
                    if (getApplicationContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Toast.makeText(get_location.this, "Got Permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                              if(location != null)
                              {
                                  Double lat = location.getLatitude();
                                  Double longt = location.getLongitude();
                                  gps_loc.setText(lat+","+longt);
                              }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(get_location.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
                }

            }
        });
        next_act.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(get_location.this, circular_menu_external.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I want to understand what is necessary to display the GPS location in the textview I made called gps_loc.

The smart watch I have is the S2 TicWatch mad eby Mobvoi and yes it does contain a GPS feature. I need to display in my textView things like the GPS among other things but the GPS is at the top of my list, but nothing seems to work. And I don't know where the problem is or what it is.

Dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.8.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:17.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation project(path: ':lvl_library')
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.8.1'
```

Permission in Manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```